# A glitch in dragging sortable by handle in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

The problem I have is that whenever I try to drag and drop with a handle, in the process of drag and drop, the body text will not stay aligned with the text, which is illustrated in the code attached at the end.

The reason why I prefer not to put the handle in the `<p>` tags, as some of the examples on the web shows, is that i would like to allow user to in place edit the stuff between the p tags, therefore i don't want to go and do a lot of pre processing (i may add more stuff around the p tags) before displaying the form.

If anyone can shed some light on this matter, it would be greatly appreciated!

Code, using Google CDN, so it should just work:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container{
        width:500;
    }
    .handle{
        float:left;
    }
    .
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#container').sortable({
            revert:true,
            handle:'.handle',
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<div id="container">
<div class="c"><span class="handle">HH</span><p>Some text here asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asd fasd fsa dfsa df asdf sadf sa dfa sdf sadf asd fsa df sadf asdf asdf asd fas df asdf as </p></div>

<div class="c"><span class="handle">HH</span><p>Some text here asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asd fasd fsa dfsa df asdf sadf sa dfa sdf sadf asd fsa df sadf asdf asdf asd fas df asdf as </p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the div is dragged to do the sorting, jQuery effectively set's the `draggable` (so `div.c` in your case) to be absolutely positioned (so it can move it around the screen). Not sure about the exact CSS quirks (maybe someone wiser than I can explain more fully), but basically your floating `.handle` acts a bit strangely in conjunction with the `p` when inside an absolutely positioned container. The margins on the `p` now appear to be set from the inside of div rather than merging with them, while the `span` is still floating to the top left of the div.

One solution is to add the same top margin to the `span` as to the `p`, but only while its dragging. In other words add the following CSS (I think `1em` should be the default margin applied to the top of the `p`):

```
.ui-sortable-helper .handle {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

If you are interested in delving more into the CSS, add the following to your above code & you'll reproduce the problem without needing the sortables involved:

```
.c { width: 500px; height: 40px; position: absolute; }
```